# Simulating Option selection in qUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unit-testing, qunit

I'm trying to write qUnit tests based around the selection of an option. However, adding a click event to the specific option doesn't work, so I've been trying to use the .change() event, but when there's more than one, I get a call stack error like this:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here's my unit Test:

```
test( "Testing",  function() {


    $('#target_select').val(5);
    $('#target_select').change();
    $('#target_select').val(6);
    $('#target_select').change();

    equal($('#some_target').is(':disabled'), true, "It's disabled, man" );


});
```

So my question is how do I either accurately simulate this event, or how do I stop this from happening? If I use only one event, the tests aren't accurate.

Comment: What is `.change` doing?

Comment: I was thinking it just instantiated the change event

Comment: Yes I know it does that I was asking what exactly does it do when it executes? What is the code behind it?

Comment: The back end is just a function that launches every change event of the select, which is just filled with a ton of conditionals, reading what value is selected and doing a bunch of random things (in this example, it would just disable the #some_target when the select is 6, but when it goes to 5, it woud disable it and vice versa. One of the reasons I'm writing unit tests for this is because I want to refactor this function heavily)

Comment: It basically is a large function with conditionals that decide arbitrary things about the page.

Comment: Okay and what does `test` do?

Comment: So first something is disabled, then a selection makes it enabled, then when you switch to the first (or another) back I want to make sure that it goes back to enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QUnit for javascript Testing on events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670357/qunit-for-javascript-testing-on-events)